# ¿Quiero saber como indicarle a un combobox en VB.NET 2012, que solo me agregue 2 opciones, "ENTRADAS y SALIDAS"?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la sentencia de mi código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta el código como texto, consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)